WSL not able to start ts server / vscode server
When I do code . in wsl, it opens the project but never stops loading the typescript server or the vscode server. So, hovering over an object or anything will indefinitely show the 'Loading...' popup. Same with ctrl + clicking on a file, it never opens it. Just infinitely loads it.
Stuff I've done:

reinstall the ubuntu on wsl
delete ~/.vscode-server folder from wsl
open my project that is on wsl path with code .
connect to the project through remote explorer extension

Doing which code on wsl properly points to /mnt/c/Users/myUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code. When I do code . and do "which code" on the vscode terminal it shows /home/myUser/.vscode-server/bin/f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813/bin/remote-cli/code.
2024-11-28 13:40:48.235 [info] Starting TS Server
2024-11-28 13:40:48.235 [info] Using tsserver from: /home/myUser/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.8.20241127/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js
2024-11-28 13:40:48.235 [info] <syntax> Forking...
2024-11-28 13:40:48.235 [info] <syntax> Starting...
2024-11-28 13:40:48.235 [info] <semantic> Forking...
2024-11-28 13:40:48.235 [info] <semantic> Starting...

Logs for 'server' (vscode) (not sure if relevant)
2024-11-28 13:40:44.768 [info] Extension host agent started.
2024-11-28 13:40:44.983 [info] [127.0.0.1][209a7f0c][ManagementConnection] New connection established.
2024-11-28 13:40:45.193 [info] [127.0.0.1][83c35b90][ExtensionHostConnection] New connection established.
2024-11-28 13:40:45.260 [info] [127.0.0.1][83c35b90][ExtensionHostConnection] <79495> Launched Extension Host Process.
2024-11-28 13:42:59.728 [error] [network] #2: https://mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0?cors=true&content-type=application/x-json-stream - error POST connect ETIMEDOUT [IP]:443

I can't seem to get to the bottom of this. What am I doing wrong?
